# python easy_install.pth for sys.path

Tags: python, easy-install

I looked at my easy_install.pth file in `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages`, which I think is the default directory when I download packages via easy_install. Inside easy_install.pth, one of the entry is the directory itself, i.e `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages`. However, when I check sys.path, `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages` is not included in the path itself.

I'm only saying this because I downloaded a package and thought I can use it simply by putting it in `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages` directory.

Comment: I think you mean `.../site-packages`, that's `site`, not `dist`.

Comment: @Keith no, Debian-based distros also put stuff in dist-packages - it's for those packages supplied by the distribution itself.

Answer (score 0):

The easy_install tool installs it in the right place for you. If you don't or can't run it as root then you can place new packages in your private locate.

```
easy_install-2.6 --user
```

Will install in your home directory.